# The correct translation of Sıkbaç

Tags: translation, cultural-phrases

There is an old dish in middle east culture. It is called as "**Sıkbaç**" in Turkish. It consists of lamb, vegetables, and various spices.

I have a translation work Turkish to English. DeepL translates it as "**dzhubach**".

I have left it as is adding an intra-glossing explanation. But DeepL makes me confused.

I want to hear answers, especially from the members from Middle-east, if its English translation "**dzhubach**" or something else.

I have not found anything on google. Additionally ChatGPT does not have information.

Comment: Do you think there is an English translation for Sikbac? Its original name is just fine

Comment: Is this the recipe? : http://eatlikeasultan.com/sikbaj-the-return/ -  *It’s made with fatty lamb chunks and a range of herbs, spices and vegetables, including, agarwood, cassia, coriander, onions, leek, carrots, and aubergine, as well as, of course, the eponymous vinegar, tempered with some dibs (date molasses) or honey.*

Comment: @Gio that is cool! Thank you.

Comment: _Dzhubach_ isn't an English word. It finds no results whatever in Google.

Comment: Per @Gio link, "**vinegar stew** known as sikbāj (سكباج), with both the dish and the name being a borrowing from Persia (sik, ‘vinegar’; bāj, ‘stew’)."

Comment: "Vinegar stew" doesn't sound very appetising, and I doubt many people in UK or US would know what to expect if they saw that on a menu. It depends what you want a translation for.